# How can check attendance from array list value in python?

Tags: python, arraylist

We're using python lists to record students who attended our class and what
order they arrived in. For example, the following list represents a class with 8
students, in which Jahurul showed up first and Arif was the last to arrive:

```
students = ['Jahurul', 'Nazmul', 'Nayeem', 'Swapna', 'Ahad', 'Munia', 'Al-amin',
'Arif']
```

A student is considered 'Excusably late' if they arrived after at least half of the
participants. However, they must not be the very last participant (that's taking
it too far). In the above example, Ahad, Munia and Al-amin are the only
students who were excusably late.
Write a function which takes a list of students and the name of one
student and prints whether that person is “excusably late”. If the student is
not in the list, `print “Student was absent”`

Comment: so what did you try?

Comment: SO is not a homework service.

Comment: Please help me.

Comment: Write some code, include it and we will help you where you got stuck.

Comment: I am new in python

Comment: Good luck, we will help when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this

```
students = []
NumberOf = int(input('enter number student: '))
half = len(students) / 2
for x in range(NumberOf):
    add = input(str('Add a student: '))
    students.append(add)
print(students)

getname = input(str('enter your letter: '))
if students.count(getname) > 0:
    index = students.index(getname)
    if index >= half:
        print("Excusably late")
    else:
        print("Not Excusably late")
else:
    print("Absent")
```